# How to tell web api ApiExplorer that the endpoint will return binary data (like a zip file)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, documentation, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

For endpoints returning models, we can use the `ResponseTypeAttribute` to tell the help page documentation what the return data will look like:

```
/// <summary>
/// returns the specified Foo.
/// </summary>
[ResponseType(typeof(FooModel))]
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/foos/{fooId}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFoo(int fooId)
{
    ...
}
```

This will make a nice entry on the Api Help page, describing how this endpoint will behave.

I want to document that a certain endpoint will return an application/zip binary stream.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you already know that your api endpoint going to return zip file then you can set it hard-coded to `application/octet-stream`.

```
content-type = "application/octet-stream"
```

Comment: Where would that get hardcoded?  I am specifically looking to have this show up in the online documentation.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the correct answer it seems.